# How to make a query to join local database and linked server database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have created a linked server and give the name as `test`.

When I write a query like

```
select * 
from openquery(test, 'select * from account')
```

it works fine but when I run this query:

```
select * 
from openquery(test, 'select * from account join test1 on account.accountid=test1.student_id')
```

it throws an error

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "test" returned message
>   "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".

I don't know what I am doing wrong to join both the server.

Comment: Try adding an alias `select t.* from openquery(test,'...') as t`

Comment: @Serg I tried its still giving the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When any of the 2 server ( linked server and local server) is using ms sql 2012 and above. Then while creating the linked server make sure Under provider    drop down we select SQL Server Native Client 11.0. The reason I was keep on   getting the error is because under Provider I selected SQL Server Native Client   10.0 and my linked server is using sql2008 and my local server is sql2012

**Solution**

```
select * from test.account.dbo.account m  
    left join  
         test t  
            on m.accountid=t.student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as:

```
select * from test.master.dbo.account 
              join 
              test.master.dbo.test1 
                      on account.accountid=test1.student_id
```

likewise:

```
select * from test.master.dbo.account
```

Comment: Its giving an error The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "test" does not contain the table ""master"."dbo"."account"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

Comment: Write the full name of table . In which db does table recide?
you should replace master with that database name
@RedDevil

Comment: I tried what you ask for but its still the same error. The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "test" does not contain the table ""test"."dbo"."test"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

Comment: Even If I run test.dbname.dbo.account it throws an error 'Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped this transaction.
'

Comment: Is your database name test? and table name test as well

Comment: yes in my test environment my linkedserver name is test, DB name is test and table name is test. I also tried with different db but its still the same

Comment: What about your schema name. Is your schemaname dbo  or anything else?

Comment: Try test.test.dbo.account 
I just noticed you were doing test.dbo.test
the format is linkedservername.databasename.schemaname.tablename
If the table exists and you have access. then i ll surely work.

Comment: select * from test.dbname.dbo.account 
              join 
              test.test.dbo.test
                      on Account.accountid=test.student_id . I ran this but its giving me the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131558/discussion-between-ranjana-ghimire-and-red-devil).

Comment: Yes sure!! message me when you are available. Thanx for your help